# .click() event does not trigger function in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I'm trying to test a button in jasmine 1.3 and jQuery 1.7.2, and when I define the .click() functions, it doesn't trigger the event. 
This is my code:

```
describe("after collection loads files", function(){

  beforeEach(function(){
    this.filesColl._processFetchBatchResult(
      constructFetchBatchResult(this.filesAttrs, {IsTruncated:false, Marker:''} ));
      clickFileCheckbox(this.filesTable, 'mySubdir', true); // I click a checkbox in a row
      this.filesTable.$('.tableview-bulk-container button').eq(0).click(); // validates is the subdir is empty and disable bulk actions
  });

  it("validates if the bulk actions are disabled", function(){
    expect(this.filesTable.$(".tableview-bulk-container ul li")            
           .hasClass("disabled")).toBeTruthy(); 

  });
```

But when I click the button, it doesn't add the class "disable" to my buttons, which works perfectly fine in the real DOM.

I also tried with .trigger('click');

Thanks.

Comment: what is `this.filesTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not familiar with Jasmine, but your click handler is empty, which is fine if you already have an action set on the button you are binding the handler to. So instead you might try something like:

```
this.filesTable.$('.tableview-bulk-container button').eq(0).click(function(){
    //this is where you do stuff, like calling another function
});
```

hope this helps.